# Get a file out of a docker container running using Kubernetes in Gitlab

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci

Gitlab is configured to execute multiple tasks and each task is running in a separate docker container. There are multiple tasks setup as:

```
stages:
  - setup
  - package
  - cleanup
  - test
```

All the containers are created using the command:

```
  script:
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY_URL/$COMPONENT:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG --file $CI_PROJECT_DIR/resources/docker/$COMPONENT/Dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/$COMPONENT:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
```

After the final stage some of the $COMPONENT creates reports which need to obtained as artifacts. But since they are getting executed in separate docker containers I am not aware how they can be fetched from the container.
I could try the below lines only if the path of artifact is with reference to $CI_PROJECT_DIR.

```
artifacts:
    paths:
      - output/
    expire_in: 1 week
```

But in My case all the containers are running using Kubernetes in Gitlab and hence final test reports of my application are residing inside each containers. What will be best way to get the documents out of the docker containers?

Comment: Why doesn't the `artifacts` work? Collecting results of the CI jobs without messing with the underlying runners (regardless of kubernetes, docker or shell executors) is precisely what the `artifacts` mechanism was designed for.

Comment: @Lukeman: I dont know how I can access the artifact from the docker container. Suppose I need the files from /home/output from the docker container. artifacts:paths needs to be written with respect to $CI_PROJECT_DIR. What should I write for artifacts:paths?